# Trouble linking something properly

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I seem to have trouble using the **link** option when sourcing a question or answer. The actual link works but does not show up *clean* ie it basically looks like when I copy & paste from the other web page. Can someone explain how to link properly using hyperlink provided?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include a link in a post or comment, put the link *text* in square brackets followed immediately by the *link* (URL) in parentheses, like this:

`[this meta question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/trouble-linking-something-properly)`

That renders as:

[this meta question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/trouble-linking-something-properly)

(There's another way to indicate links, but I find the one I've shown you to be easier to work with.)

You can find more formatting tips by clicking on the "?" icon above the editing box on the right.

Comment: This way works across the board, whereas the other way only works for posts.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion & it worked.